# chrome.notifications.create is not working, alarm is created but no notification shows

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a notification upon an alarm, but while the alarm seems to work, the notification does not show up. Any advice would be appreciated!

background.js

```
'use strict';

chrome.alarms.create({when: Date.now()+1200, periodInMinutes: 20});

chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(function(alarm) {
    console.log("Got an alarm!", alarm);
    chrome.notifications.create('reminder', {
            type: 'basic',
            iconUrl: 'icon_100.png',
            title: 'Break Time!',
            message: 'You\'ve been staring at the screen for 20 minutes, take a break!'
        });
});
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Break Time",
  "version": "1.0",
  "icons": {
    "100": "icon_100.png"
  },
  "description": "Take a break from the computer every 20 min",
  "permissions": ["alarms", "notifications"],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Comment: can you give the error message?

Comment: [Where to read console messages from background.js in a Chrome extension?](//stackoverflow.com/q/10257301)

Answer (score 0):

The iconUrl should point to a valid url. In your case if you have the file in the extension folder it would be:

```
chrome.extension.getURL("/icon_100.png")
```